# Google Authenticator ValidateTwoFactorPIN(UserUniqueKey, token) siempre false MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth

estoy tratando de implementar 2FA con el autenticador de Google, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Estoy siguiendo el siguiente artículo
[Two-Factor Authentication using Google Authenticator in asp.net mvc](http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/two-factor-authentication-in-aspnet-mvc)

He leído que tengo que sincronizar la corrección de tiempo para los códigos, pero cuando intento la aplicación de autenticación de Google dice que la hora ya es correcta

¿Alguna idea? Gracias

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private const string key = "Max@123456"; // any 10-12 char string for use as private key in google authenticator
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel login)
{
    string message = "";
    bool status = false;

    //check username and password form our database here
    //for demo I am going to use Admin as Username and Password1 as Password static value
    if (login.Username == "Admin" && login.Password == "Password1")
    {
        status = true; // show 2FA form
        message = "2FA Verification";
        Session["Username"] = login.Username;

        //2FA Setup
        TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
        string UserUniqueKey = login.Username + key; //as Its a demo, I have done this way. But you should use any encrypted value here which will be unique value per user 
        Session["UserUniqueKey"] = UserUniqueKey;
        var setupInfo = tfa.GenerateSetupCode("NAVIGIA 2FA", login.Username, UserUniqueKey, 300, 300);
        ViewBag.BarcodeImageUrl = setupInfo.QrCodeSetupImageUrl;
        ViewBag.SetupCode = setupInfo.ManualEntryKey;
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Invalid credential";
    }
    ViewBag.Message = message;
    ViewBag.Status = status;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult MyProfile()
{
    if (Session["Username"] == null || Session["IsValid2FA"] == null || !(bool)Session["IsValid2FA"])
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome " + Session["Username"].ToString();
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Verify2FA()
{
    var token = Request["passcode"];
    TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
    string UserUniqueKey = Session["UserUniqueKey"].ToString();
    bool isValid = tfa.ValidateTwoFactorPIN(UserUniqueKey, token);
    if (isValid)
    {
        Session["IsValid2FA"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Home");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solucion a mi problema y era que mi pc estaba en una zona horaria incorrecta. Solo la ajuste a automatic time and zone. Hora y zona horaria automatica.